# onBackPressed() method not triggered in AppCompatActivity

Tags: android

AppCompatActivity onBackPressed() method fails to trigger in my activity.

I see the back arrow button and get the animation when pressing it, but nothing else happens. also overriding onKeyDown() has the same effect. it's not called.

I've spent many hours researching this with no luck. Nothing seems to work. Anyone has had a similar issue? Maybe this is a known bug?

My Activity.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.litenote.android.BackTestingActivity2Activity">
<include
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar" />
<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

app_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/appBar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/primary"
android:titleTextAppearance="@color/textWhite"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
android:popupTheme="@style/CustomPopupMenuTheme">
```

The activity Java file

```
package com.litenote.android;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;

import com.superpad.android.R;

public class BackTestingActivity2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_back_testing_activity2);
    Toolbar actionBar = ((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appBar));
    setSupportActionBar(actionBar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.d("BACK_BUTTON_DOESNT_WORK", "I will never execute and you will never see me :(");
    super.onBackPressed();
    this.finish();
}
}
```

Comment: Catch back button on key method, and call `onBackPressed()`

Comment: If I override my Activity onKeyDown(), that doesn't get called either, even though button is there and I can press it

Comment: what back arrow is that? `onBackPressed` is for the physical back button, next to the home button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your manifest file define the following inside your activity tag:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.ParentActivity" />
```

After that in your activity:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is it, Thank you so much! you made my day :)

Answer (score 8):

I believe `onBackPressed()` is only called when the physical back button is pressed.  If you're attempting to catch the toolbar back button press (the navigation icon), try using the following snippet:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: {
            // Your code here
        }
    }
    return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**onBackPressed()** is not present in ***AppCompactActivity***,
You have to implement an *InterFace* **KeyEvent.Callback** and override **onKeyUp method** and check if the key is BackButton or you can extend  **ActionBarActivity** which is child class of ***AppCompactActivity***

Comment: Can you provide references that support this claim?

Answer (score 3):

**back_button on the actionbar**

*this will wok*

```
Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appBar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
super.onBackPressed();
this.finish();
```

}

or
*set which activity load when click back*

```
<meta-data
android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
android:value="com.example.ParentActivity" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. Obviously there isn't all the code, but i think it can usefull for you to understand how to implements the backPressed event.

```
public class RedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ...
  }

  ...

  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    if (isDrawerOpen()) {
      drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
      getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
     //Ask the user if they want to quit
     new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .setTitle(R.string.quit)
                        .setMessage(R.string.really_quit)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {        
                                finish();
                            }

                        })
          .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null)
          .show();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: My issue is that, onBackPressed() is not called at all. your code assumes that it has been called.

Comment: The difference are in "onCreate" method. I didn't add meta-data to manifest.

Comment: I've tried with setHomeAsUpIndicator() but with the same result... onBackPressed is not called. It makes sense though, from my accepted answer I realize that this is AppBar event, not a back press which comes from clicking android triangle pointing left. I confused these two because in some Activities both are triggered in the same scenario, go figure...

Answer (score -1):

This is what you need to add

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: onBackPressed() is not available in AppCompatActivity