# @Override doesn't work with android annotation?

Tags: android, android-annotations

I just try to rewrite onBackPressed(), but it is absent in geerated code, so text in my overrided onBackPressed() is ignoring.

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_before_test_warning)
public class BeforeTestWarningActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onBackPressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
}
```

With this code "back" arrow touching is behaving normally, i.e. creates new parent activity and toast not shows. Why?

I just want to return to previous page with filled form if user did not confirm the move further, but pressed "back" to edit some kind of mistakes.

Comment: You need to override `onBackPressed()` on the activity you're currently on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onBackPressed() method not triggered in AppCompatActivity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681141/onbackpressed-method-not-triggered-in-appcompatactivity)

Comment: Above code is working fine , But can you pass ActivityName.this in to makeText method instead of only this.

Comment: I need to override `onBackPressed()` to get same behave as by clicking on my "cancel" button, when I just returns to saved, not recreated, previous activity: `@Click
 void btCancel() {
  Toast.makeText(this, "btCancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  finish(); }`. Back button by default just create new parent activity.

Answer (score 0):

try to add super.onBackPressed()

```
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
      super.onBackPressed();
      Toast.makeText(this, "onBackPressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      finish(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use standart behavior. I need to back to my previous activity without it's recreate as by pressing back.

Comment: Yes this is the case, if you override onBackPressed as this (only by calling the super) your activity will return to de previous activity. and you can change this behaviors if you want you can put your code after   super.onBackPressed();

Comment: Problem is that when I using android annotation, all this method is ignored. Toast "onBackPressed" newer shows.

Answer (score 0):

AndroidAnnotations does not modify `@Override` or `onBackPressed()` in any way.

The correct way to override `onBackPressed()` for your case is this:

```
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
      Toast.makeText(this, "onBackPressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      super.onBackPressed(); 
  }
```

You must call `super.onBackPressed()`, because it does necessary things, like popping your `Fragment`s and running `Activity` transitions. And it will call `finish()` finally.